# Rich snippets (RDFa) not appearing in search results

Tags: html, rich-snippets, rdfa

I have the following RDFa rich snippet at the top of a web page (ref: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en#aggregate):

```
<div class="site-reviews">
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" typeof="v:Review-aggregate">
<span property="v:itemreviewed">[Product]</span>
<span rel="v:rating">
  <span typeof="v:Rating">
   <span property="v:average">5</span>
   out of
   <span property="v:best">5</span>
   </span>
</span>
based on
<span property="v:votes">8</span> votes.
</div>
</div>
```

However, rather than showing the usual stars in the search result, it displays the text result "[Product] 5 out of 5 based on 462 votes." as the meta-description. Where am I going wrong?

***UPDATE** (anonymised) google search result below:

[image]

Comment: Is Google displaying this as some kind of Rich Snippet (but without the star image), or is this an extract of your page content?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or a link please? I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Please see screenshot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the semantic web and search engine optimization